# In react-admin how can I change label of showButton according to my data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin

```
const MySaveButton = ({...props}) => {
  const {record, source} = props;
  if (!record || !source) return null;
  return <ShowButton {...props} label={record[source] === SenderReviewStatus['pendingReview'] ? "Review" : "Detall"} />
}
```

At the beginning record[source] === SenderReviewStatus['pendingReview'] is true, and after I review, the button label should change to "Detail" from "Review". However, mySaveButton always show "Review" even if the record[source] === SenderReviewStatus['pendingReview'] has been changed to false form true.

Comment: (record[source] === SenderReviewStatus['pendingReview'])? ,Try this may work

Answer (score 0):

I know! Showbutton has a shouldUpdate HOC whith limit the condition.

https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/v2.9.4/packages/ra-ui-materialui/src/button/SaveButton.js